# how to bind ajaxStart/ajaxStop to a form?

Tags: jquery

How to bind ajaxStart/ajaxStop to a form?

I need a loading block to show while uploading the file

Now the form is not submitted at all

```
var iframe = $('<iframe name="iframe_file_upload" src="'+src_file_upload+'" style="display:none"></iframe>');
var btn_send = $('<input type="button" />')
    .click(function(){
        $('#form_upload_file').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
            $(this).submit();
        });
        iframe.bind('ajaxStop', function(){
            $(this).load(function(){
                ...
```

## update

```
var btn_send = $('<input type="button" />')
    .click(function(){
        $('#form_upload_file').ajaxForm(
            $('#form_upload_file').ajaxForm({
                success : function(response){
                    // the response is a string?! how can the response be retrieved as an JSON object?
                    alert(response);
                }
            }
        }).submit();
    });
```

Comment: try `$("#form_upload_file").ajaxStart(function(){
   iframe.show();
 });`

Comment: the iframe has to stay hidden.. the file is uploaded from the iframe

Comment: what you want to display then??

Comment: Don't handle the iframe stuff on your own. use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) - the nice thing is that it can even use XHR uploads if the browser is modern enough! And it gives you all the callbacks no matter if it's a real XHR or an iframe-based faked XHR.

Comment: thief > how do I get the response from the iframe when using `ajaxForm`?

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: got it :) theifmaster.. create an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//initially hide your loading block
$('#loadingblock').hide();

//submit form using ajax-request
$('#yourform').submit(function(){
$.post('formhandle.php',$(this).serialize(),function(){alert('form submitted!')});
//prevent default submission
return false;
}

//now the loader part
$('#loadingblock').ajaxStart(function(){$(this).show();})
.ajaxStop(function(){$(this).hide();});
```

Comment: and if you dont want to do this on form submission, then change the event submit to click or something. And instead of serialize, send your file input data.